# Как правильно получить IBM из TRS матрицы трансформации суставов?

Tags: c#, матрицы, 3d

Пишу кастомный конвертер трехмерной графики из специфичного формата в glTF. При экспорте скининга, столкнулся с проблемой получения inverseBindMatrices для суставов скелета.
На входе есть матрица 4x4 для каждого сустава. При декомпозиции матрицы до TRS получаю валидные vector3 для перемещения, vector4 кватернион для вращения и vector3 для масштабирования, в blender после экспорта скелет выглядит корректно, TRS-анимация так же работает корректно. Меш при этом вывернут наизнанку, т.к. не хватает инверсной матрицы для локальных преобразований.
Никак не могу понять, как правильно получить матрицу IBM, имея на входе матрицу TRS. Пробовал варианты преобразования из мировых в локальные и обратно, а так же по формуле, предлагаемой официальной спецификацией glTF, но безрезультатно.

Comment: TRS'ы  локальные или в мировой фрейм? Если в мировой фрейм, то надо собрать матрицы и обратить. Если локальные, то надо перемножить матрицы вверх по скелету (или просто перевести в мировой фрейм - должна быть такая операция) и обратить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, помог второй вариант! Перевел матрицы костей в мировой фрейм перемножением на родителей, затем инвертировал. Скелет выровнялся, меш почти корректен. Как мне быть с матрицами корневых костей? У связанного меша нет никаких трансформаций, поэтому корневые матрицы я умножил на mat4.identity, но видимо это неправильное решение, т.к. рут-кости неверно трансформированы и это видно в blender.

Comment: Матрицы корневых костей включите в произведение перед обращением. Матрица меша в мировом фрейме единичная?

Comment: Можно поступить проще: сделать общий рут для всех рутовых костей и кожи. Матрица кожи под общим рутом должна быть единичная. Матрицы костей умножать вплоть до этого рута.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вопрос снят, умножать на identity корректный вариант, просто в исходной матрице скаляры translate хранились в последнем столбце, а не строчке, я разобрался :) Еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Решение - [ответ Станислава](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356525/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ibm-%D0%B8%D0%B7-trs-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2#comment2406990_1356525).